# How can I change the default (system) search engine for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, search, search-engines, bing

I would like to change the default system search engine from Bing to Google. I don't mean the default search engine of any browser, but the search engine that is used when searching in the windows search bar, or entering "?something" in the file explorer address bar.

I don't think windows has any built in way of doing this, but I would be happy for any workaround.

Comment: Did you try MSEdgeRedirect? https://github.com/rcmaehl/MSEdgeRedirect

Comment: This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has baked their search engine into the OS. You can change the default browser and the default search engine in the browser. You can install 3rd party local search utilies as well.

But you cannot change the engine Microsoft uses in their UI elements.